# Adding multiple nodes to Default Intent dialog in Kore.ai

Tags: bots, chatbot

Is there any way to add sub intents or entities to the Default Intent node. I can add one entity or intent node to the Default Intent node but it doesn't allow adding multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple intents can be added - but it needs to be with prompt.If you are designing a question - where a user can request for 'checking out a Jaguar' - you can either design the bot to directly look for the car and prompt the answer, or you can provide an additional step - where in the bot can ask to specify 'did you mean the car or the animal' - this will help branch out the intents properly & the correct entity can be extracted and be prompted to the user.So entity extraction can either happen directly, or can be designed in multiple steps - depending on the intent defined. I hope i have given you the answer for your question, if you have any query regarding Kore.ai please reach out to me on nishant.mohanty@kore.com .